# mysql - how to select data from next month

Tags: mysql, date

i have table with `id`, `date_from`, `date_to` fileds.
I need to find all the data where date_to +1 month is equal to condition

for example>
if data in `date_to` field is `2015-06-01` and `WHERE` condition is `2015-07-01` i should get the result

```
SELECT *, (date_to + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as 'next' FROM table_name WHERE 'next'='2015-07-01'
```

this is my query, that obviously doesn't work ;)

Tnx in adavance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can not use alias in the where condition and also  the condition is wrong. It will be

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 
date_add(date_to,interval 1 month)='2015-07-01'
```

Now note that for large data-set its not a good idea to use function on the date filed since even if the field is index it will fail to use index. So better to use the function on the data to be filtered rather than on the field. So the above query could be written as

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE 
date_to= date_sub('2015-07-01',interval 1 month)
```